# Acess denied for user connecting Mysql java

Tags: java, mysql

When I'm trying to get connetcion with online mysql database I get this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'89.229.59.50' (using password: NO)

My code is:

```
 public static Statement stmt = null;
 public static Connection conn = null;
 private static final String dbURL ="jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306/dolar;user=neir@localhost&password=password";

 private static void createConnection() {
    try {
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);       
    } catch (Exception except) {
        except.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And yes, I've added mysql connector to my project.

Comment: You might not have enough privillages

Comment: did you check username and password with mysql

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the user (neir) has remote access privileges.

If your using a hosting service make sure they allow your remote IP (89.229.59.50) to connect to MySQL Server.

If you're managing the MySQL Server make sure that it's configured to be accessed remotely, that's done in the my.cnf file, search and comment the line:

**bind-address = 127.0.0.1**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From the error you can already see that the user and password parameters are not used. This might give you a clue that there is something wrong with the JDBC connection URL.

You cannot put the user and password parameters in the connection URL.
You should use: `getConnection(String url, String user, String password)`

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0):

This might be for user has not access privileges so you should do this.

```
CREATE USER 'enterusername'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' IDENTIFIED BY 'enterpassword';
```

Where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is you IP or if you want to do this for any IP then just write '%' instead 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'

To grant privileges

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mor.* TO 'enterusername'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' WITH GRANT OPTION ;
```